# Pass cfdocument variable to form on separate page

Tags: forms, pdf, coldfusion, cfdocument

I have a form page that creates a pdf using the cfdocument tag when the page is processed. Also on that process page is a link to the next form, the user clicks on it and is taken to a new page with a new form. That form actions a new page, which processes all of its information. What I want is to have access to the pdf that I create on the first form so that I can send it in an email on the process page of the second form. I'm thinking there has to be a way to pass the variable to each page since one will always action to the next until I get to the second form process page.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Save the PDF to a the file system, then you can serve that PDF as well as use it as an attachment to an email.

FYI, you may pass any variables across pages by putting them in Session scope.  Some framework calls it the "[Flash](http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/FlashRAM.cfm)" scope, and have the variables removed from Session scope at the destination page.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but it won't really work because I'll have a lot of submissions and I don't want to store all of those pdfs on my server. The session scope idea is interesting and I will try to explore it further. I think my best option may be to just query the data again from my database and re-make the pdf on the second page. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Regarding storing files, you could have a scheduled job that deletes files that have been there longer than the interval of your choice.  Or, you can use the CFMailParam "Remove" Attribute as described here ==> http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1214-New-ColdFusion-CFMailParam-Remove-Attribute-Makes-Deleting-Attachments-Simple.htm